# Is there a way to start a virtual device automatically when Android Studio is started?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I just wondered if there is a way to configure **Android Studio** such that it **automatically starts** a specific virtual device (**AVD**) in the **emulator** when i start Android Studio itsself.

Thank you in advance!
Marc

Comment: i think the only way will be doing a batch file that opens Android Studio and the AVD from the folder at the same time

Comment: for example to open an avd of your choise you can use

Comment: $ /Users/janedoe/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23 -netdelay none -netspeed full

Comment: is stated here https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Comment: which os is it windows or linux

Comment: It's Windows. I'll try that out. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always forget emulator command options and my avd names so I made a bat script that show all the avds defined and let me choose which one start. I quite often need to start an avd without waiting Android Studio up and running. Could this solve your problem ?
I called it avdmanager.bat in root of SDK (variable ANDROID_HOME set on SDK root needed):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=0
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -
list-avds`) DO (
  SET /a count=!count!+1
  SET var!count!=%%F
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%count%) do echo %%i) !var%%i!
@echo digit number of virtual machine to run or 'q' to quit
set /p choice=""
if "%choice%"=="q" goto end
@echo !var%choice%!
%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -avd !var%choice%!
:end
ENDLOCAL
```